# Unable to uninstall package inside virtualenv

Tags: virtualenv, pip, virtualenvwrapper

I installed virtualenv + virtualenvwrapper via [virtualenv-burrito](https://github.com/brainsik/virtualenv-burrito). However, it seems to be giving me problems now in uninstalling packages from my virtualenvs (case in point, `distribute`).

It seems that the `distribute` used by my virtualenvs is the one at `/home/skrd/.venvburrito`. If, inside a virtualenv, I try to upgrade `distribute`, it installs to `/home/skrd/.virtualenvs` but the virtualenv itself is still using the one at `/home/skrd/.venvburrito`. With that, the packages needing an updated `distribute` still won't work.

See,

```
(test)$ $ pip uninstall distribute
Not uninstalling distribute at /home/skrd/.venvburrito/lib/python/distribute-0.6.27-py2.7.egg, outside environment /home/skrd/.virtualenvs/test
```

I've tried renaming the `.venvburrito` directory (equivalent to deleting it, but with back-up) but that breaks my virtualenvs. How do I uninstall packages now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still don't understand what happened here but I just had the idea to check what's installed for my system's Python outside virtualenv. There I saw distribute, with a similar version to the one that's giving me problems inside a virtualenv.

I upgraded the non-virtualenv installation of distribute and, next time I checked in my virtualenv, the distribute installation has also upgraded.

(So, yes, I'm aware that my question's original intent is to remove distribute. But that was just an intermediary step to updating it---the update was unable to proceed since it can't remove the distribute currently installed. So, there, problem solved.)